# Русский, городской

Tags: грамотная-речь

Что значит "шмурдяк"? Как, и когда его используют?

Comment: Что значит "русский, городской"?

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря ненормативной лексики**

Шмурдяк (также шмурдячок) (груб.-простор.) -  самогон, некачественное спиртное.

Примеры:

Напишут, что я открыл в горах производство "шмурдячка" - самогоном из дикой груши подторговываю.

Можно деньги, полученные от рекламы качественных товаров, а не какого-нибудь "шмурдяка", пустить на развитие культуры и здравоохранения.

Answer (score 1):

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BA): Шмурдяк - суррогатный спиртной напиток, дешёвое (как правило, креплёное) низкокачественное плодово-ягодное вино.

[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%91%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0): Бормотуха была очень распространена по всему СССР с конца 1950-х до середины 1980-х гг. В народе прозывались «плодово-выгодными винами», «подло-ягодными», «чернилами», «гомулами», «червивкой», также встречаются прозвища «бырло», «шмурда», «шмурдяк», «гнилушка»...

> Слово, я думаю, одесского происхождения. У нас так называют
> креплёные вина и вина, созданные методом купажирования, низкого
> качества, а также несульфатированные вина, полученные только методом
> сбраживания. К шмурдякам у нас относят молодые вина краткосрочного
> хранения типа "божоле", а также все домашние неосветленные продукты
> сбраживания.

[Ещё](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1504874-chto-takoe-shmurdjak.html) любопытное:

> Относительно происхождения этого слова слышал интересную версию,
> похожую на правду. Шмурдяк была фамилия директора винно-водочного
> завода, производившего продукцию весьма низкого качества, во
> Владивостоке в 50-60-е годы прошлого века, ставшая там нарицательной,
> а затем слово распространилось по всей стране.

См. также "[Прощание с шмурдяком](http://lenta.ru/articles/2015/03/08/premiumvino1/)", и на этом бормотушные толкования заканчиваются, начинается "расширенный подход"...

В статье "[Оленные люди](http://compal.su/master-winch-expedition/152/685/)" шмурдяк употребляется трижды - в значении незначительные вещи, всякое барахло, имущество по [мелочовке](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=261812), пожитки:

> В свободные места мы затолкали пустые канистры под топливо, некоторый
> шмурдяк и снаряжение и даже убралась спутниковая тарелка для наших
> знакомых в Приполярном...

То есть мы получаем общее значение: что дешёвое пойло, что незатейливый скарб (см. Барахло [2](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BB%D0%BE&all=x)).

См. также [ЛО](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1504874-chto-takoe-shmurdjak.html) на "Большом вопросе":

> Ну, вообще-то это жаргонное словечко. В подавляющем большинстве
> случаев оно означает какой-то осадок или остаток, который нельзя
> использовать по прямому назначению. Так, например, это может чайная
> заварка при приготовлении чифира в местах не столь отдалённых. Или
> какой-то мутный и непонятный осадок на дне бутылки вина сомнительного
> качества. Также это могут быть сгустки краски после её фильтрования
> через сеточку и тому подобное. В общем и целом  - это всякая разная
> муть, отстой, осадок, гуща, и т.д.

И в [заключение](http://offroadclub.ru/id_1693/id_12423/id_12426/id_56982.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Шмурдяк (шмурдень) - это различный хлам из цветного и черного металла,
> который постоянно попадается под катушку.
>
> Это хлам, мусор, неликвидные находки, никому не нужный материал,
> обломки и какалики, не поддающиеся определению и восстановлению.

([Из определений кладоискателей](http://clubklad.ru/blog/article/556/))

Одно специфическое упоминание, небезынтересное:

шмурдяк - это суп, "[каторый готовят на костре](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XFWgMdXap88J:https://otvet.mail.ru/question/7468429%20&cd=10&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)"!

---

Поистине многозначное слово, вкусное!